# How to prevent a custom view to draw over itself?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-custom-view

I'm developing a Sudoku app on Android and I can't prevent my custom view (the sudoku board) to draw over itself. I'm quite new to app development, so I can't understand what's happening. Basically when I pass a board to the GameActivity the custom view in there draws the new board over the older ones. This should not happen. Any help would be appriciated.

This is my custom View.

```
public class SudokuBoardView extends View {

    private static final String TAG = "SUDOKUVIEWGRID";

    //Paints
    private Paint thinPaint;
    private Paint thickPaint;
    private Paint selectedCellPaint;
    private Paint textPaint;

    //Values
    private static int width;
    private static int height;
    private static final int padding = 64;
    private static final int SIZE = 9;
    private static final int SQRT_SIZE = 3;
    private float cellSizePixels;

    //Model
    private SudokuModel sudokuModel = null;

    public SudokuBoardView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(null);
    }

    public SudokuBoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public SudokuBoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public SudokuBoardView(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
        init(attrs);
    }

    public void init(@Nullable AttributeSet attributeSet) {

        //Paint più sottile per celle
        thinPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        thinPaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        thinPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        thinPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //Paint più spesso per contorni
        thickPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        thickPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);
        thickPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        thickPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //Paint per celle selezionate
        selectedCellPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        selectedCellPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        selectedCellPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);

        //Paint per numeri
        textPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        textPaint.setTextSize(32);
        textPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        //Dimensioni della griglia e delle celle
        width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;  //Dim. assoluta dello schermo
        height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
        cellSizePixels = (float) ((width - 2*padding)/ SIZE);

    }

    public void setSudokuModel(SudokuModel model) {
        this.sudokuModel = model;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        //Outside Border
        canvas.drawRoundRect(padding,padding, width - padding, width - padding, 20, 20, thickPaint);
        //Cells
        drawLines(canvas);
        if (sudokuModel.isNewGame()) {
            drawInitialBoard(canvas, sudokuModel.getBoard());
        }
    }

    public void cleanCells() {
        invalidate();
    }

    protected void drawLines(Canvas canvas){
        //Linee Verticali
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            //Linea più spessa ogni 3 linee (la prima viene saltata perché c'è già il bordo)
            if (i == 0) continue;
            if (i % SQRT_SIZE == 0) {
                canvas.drawLine( i*cellSizePixels + padding, padding, i*cellSizePixels + padding, width - padding, thickPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawLine( i*cellSizePixels + padding, padding, i*cellSizePixels + padding, width - padding, thinPaint);
            }
        }

        //Linee Orizzontali
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            //Linea più spessa ogni 3 linee (la prima viene saltata perché c'è già il bordo)
            if (i == 0) continue;
            if (i % SQRT_SIZE == 0) {
                canvas.drawLine( padding, i*cellSizePixels + padding, width - padding, i*cellSizePixels + padding, thickPaint);
            } else {
                canvas.drawLine(padding, i * cellSizePixels + padding, width - padding, i * cellSizePixels + padding, thinPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    public void drawInitialBoard(Canvas canvas, Board board) {
        for (Cell cell: board.getCellList()) {
            int value = cell.getValue();
            String valueText = Integer.toString(value);
            int row = cell.getRow();
            int col = cell.getCol();

            Rect textBounds = new Rect();
            textPaint.getTextBounds(valueText, 0, valueText.length(), textBounds);
            float textWidth = textPaint.measureText(valueText);
            float textHeight = textBounds.height();

            canvas.drawText((value == 0 ? "" : valueText), (row * cellSizePixels + cellSizePixels/2 - textWidth/2 + padding), (col*cellSizePixels + cellSizePixels/2 + thickPaint.getStrokeWidth() + padding), textPaint);
        }
    }


}
```

And this is the GameActivity where the view is.

```
public class GameActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Controls Buttons
    Button[] buttons = new Button[10];
    private static final int[] BUTTON_IDS = {
            R.id.button1,
            R.id.button2,
            R.id.button3,
            R.id.button4,
            R.id.button5,
            R.id.button6,
            R.id.button7,
            R.id.button8,
            R.id.button9,
            R.id.buttonCancel
    };

    NumbersOnClickListener numbersOnClickListener;
    private Board board;
    private SudokuModel sudokuModel;
    private SudokuBoardView sudokuBoardView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        /*
        * NEW GAME
        *
        * Board Setup
        * */
        Intent gameIntent = getIntent();
        boolean isNewGame = gameIntent.getBooleanExtra("new game", false);
        if (isNewGame) {
            board = gameIntent.getParcelableExtra("Board");
            sudokuModel = new SudokuModel(board, isNewGame);
            sudokuModel.getBoard().printBoard();
            sudokuBoardView = findViewById(R.id.sudokuView);
            sudokuBoardView.setSudokuModel(sudokuModel);
        }

        //Controls Setup
        numbersOnClickListener = new NumbersOnClickListener();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            buttons[i] = findViewById(BUTTON_IDS[i]);
            buttons[i].setOnClickListener(numbersOnClickListener);
            GridLayout.LayoutParams params = (GridLayout.LayoutParams) buttons[i].getLayoutParams();
            params.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels / 7;
            params.height = params.width;
            buttons[i].setLayoutParams(params);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

 }
```

The SudokuModel class.

```
public class SudokuModel {

   private Board board;
   private boolean isNewGame;
   private int selectedRow = -1;
   private int selectedCol = -1;

   public SudokuModel(Board board, boolean isNewGame) {
       this.board = board;
       this.isNewGame = isNewGame;
   }

   public Board getBoard() {
       return board;
   }

   public void setBoard(Board board) {
       this.board = board;
   }

   public boolean isNewGame() {
       return isNewGame;
   }

   public int getSelectedRow() {
       return selectedRow;
   }

   public int getSelectedCol() {
       return selectedCol;
   }

   public void setSelectedRow(int selectedRow) {
       this.selectedRow = selectedRow;
   }

   public void setSelectedCol(int selectedCol) {
       this.selectedCol = selectedCol;
   }
}
```

The Board class.

```
public class Board implements Parcelable {

   private static final int SIZE = 9;
   private ArrayList<Cell> cellList = new ArrayList<>();

   public Board(ArrayList<Cell> cellList) {
       this.cellList = cellList;
   }

   public ArrayList<Cell> getCellList() {
       return cellList;
   }

   public void setCellList(ArrayList<Cell> cellList) {
       this.cellList = cellList;
   }

   public void printBoard () {
       for (Cell cell: cellList) {
           System.out.println("Cell " + cell.getRow() + ":" + cell.getCol() + " VALUE: " + cell.getValue());
       }
   }

   protected Board(Parcel in) {
       if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
           cellList = new ArrayList<Cell>();
           in.readList(cellList, Cell.class.getClassLoader());
       } else {
           cellList = null;
       }
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       if (cellList == null) {
           dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
       } else {
           dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
           dest.writeList(cellList);
       }
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Board> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Board>() {
       @Override
       public Board createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Board(in);
       }

       @Override
       public Board[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Board[size];
       }
   };
}
```

The Cell class.

```
public class Cell implements Parcelable {

   private int row;
   private int col;
   private int value;

   public Cell(int row, int col, int value) {
       this.row = row;
       this.col = col;
       this.value = value;
   }

   public int getRow() {
       return row;
   }

   public void setRow(int row) {
       this.row = row;
   }

   public int getCol() {
       return col;
   }

   public void setCol(int col) {
       this.col = col;
   }

   public int getValue() {
       return value;
   }

   public void setValue(int value) {
       this.value = value;
   }

   protected Cell(Parcel in) {
       row = in.readInt();
       col = in.readInt();
       value = in.readInt();
   }

   @Override
   public int describeContents() {
       return 0;
   }

   @Override
   public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
       dest.writeInt(row);
       dest.writeInt(col);
       dest.writeInt(value);
   }

   @SuppressWarnings("unused")
   public static final Parcelable.Creator<Cell> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Cell>() {
       @Override
       public Cell createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
           return new Cell(in);
       }

       @Override
       public Cell[] newArray(int size) {
           return new Cell[size];
       }
   };
}
```

Here is where the board is generated and passed to the game activity.

```
public class SudokuGenerator implements Response.ErrorListener, Response.Listener<JSONObject> {

    private static final String TAG = "SUDOKU_GENERATOR";
    private String url = "https://sugoku.herokuapp.com/board?difficulty=";
    public int[][] puzzle = new int[9][9];
    ArrayList<Cell> generatedPuzzleCells = new ArrayList<>();
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private Context context;
    LoadingDialog loadingDialog;
    NewGameErrorDialog newGameErrorDialog;

    public SudokuGenerator(Context context) {
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.loadingDialog = new LoadingDialog((Activity) context);
        this.newGameErrorDialog = new NewGameErrorDialog((Activity) context);
    }

    public int[][] getPuzzle() {
        return puzzle;
    }

    public void setPuzzle(int[][] puzzle) {
        this.puzzle = puzzle;
    }

    public void setDifficulty(int difficulty) {
        switch (difficulty){
            case Globals.EASY:
                url = url.concat("easy");
                break;
            case Globals.MEDIUM:
                url = url.concat("medium");
                break;
            case Globals.HARD:
                url = url.concat("hard");
                break;
            default:
                url = url.concat("random");
                break;
        }
    }

    public void puzzleGenerator (int difficulty) {
        loadingDialog.startLoadingDialog();
        setDifficulty(difficulty);
        System.out.println("Set Difficulty");
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,null,this, this);
        requestQueue.add(request);
        System.out.println("Made request");
        url = "https://sugoku.herokuapp.com/board?difficulty=";
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        System.out.println("ERROR Response");
        newGameErrorDialog.startErrorDialog();
        loadingDialog.dismissDialog();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

        System.out.println("Response");
        //Check if not empty
        if (response.length() == 0){

        } //Error Handling

        try {
            JSONArray board = response.getJSONArray("board");
            System.out.println("Board " + board);
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length(); i++) {
                JSONArray box = board.getJSONArray(i);
                for (int j = 0; j < box.length(); j++) {
                    int k = box.getInt(j);
                    Cell cell;
                    if (k == 0) {
                        cell = new Cell(i, j, k, 0);
                    } else {
                        cell = new Cell(i, j, k, 1);
                    }
                    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: GENERATED CELL: " + i +" "+j+" : "+k+" "+cell.isStartingCell());
                    generatedPuzzleCells.add(cell);
                }
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Board generatedBoard = new Board(generatedPuzzleCells);
        generatedBoard.printBoard();
        loadingDialog.dismissDialog();
        Intent gameIntent = new Intent(context, GameActivity.class);
        gameIntent.putExtra("Board", generatedBoard);
        gameIntent.putExtra("new game",true);
        context.startActivity(gameIntent);
    }
}
```

Here are two screenshots of what happens on the first tap of the new game (how it should be) and what happens after going back to main activity (where the new game button is) and pressing the button again.

[image: First Tap]

[image: After other taps]

Comment: Please post your `SudokuModel` class.

Comment: Sorry, we'll need the `Board` class, too, then. I'd assumed it was a nested class.

Comment: Hmm, my first thought was that you had a `static` list of `Cell`s in `Board` that had two games added to it inadvertently, but that's not the case. Now I'm thinking that you might be somehow adding two games to the `ArrayList<Cell>` passed to `Board` in your `MainActivity` somewhere. When you go to `GameActivity` the second time, what does your `sudokuModel.getBoard().printBoard();` show? Does it have more `Cell`s than it should?

Comment: I think you should see where the board is created. I edited the post.

Comment: Are you creating a new `SudokuGenerator` instance for each new game? Or are you using the same one over and over? The `generatedPuzzleCells` list is never cleared, so if you're using the same `SudokuGenerator` instance repeatedly, then it looks like you're possibly just adding the new game to the last one. What do you see from the `sudokuModel.getBoard().printBoard();` the second time you go to `GameActivity`?

Comment: Also, just to clarify, your custom `View` isn't really drawing over itelf. Every time `onDraw()` is called, you're handed a "blank" `Canvas`, so about the only things that explain the observed behavior are: you have multiple `SudokuBoardView`s stacked one atop another (which seems unlikely), or the `SudokuBoardView` is just drawing more than it should at one time, which leads to my suspicion that you're ending up with multiple games in your list.

Comment: Yes you're right. The problem was that I was using the same SudokuGenerator instance on every tap on the button. Creating a new one after the tap solved the problem. Thank you so much.

Comment: No problem. You might not need a new `SudokuGenerator` each time, though, if you can clear `generatedPuzzleCells` before adding the new game to it. Just a thought. Anyhoo, glad you got it working. Cheers!